# Rendering quarto book to an alternative directory than _book

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, render, quarto

I am using quarto and enjoying it very much.  Getting some good feedback on the reports from customers.

I would like to use the same qmd files to generate reports for 10 different customers and be able to publish them.  Using RSTudio.  I have a parameter which defines the customer.  Currently the finished reports are stored in directory _book.  I would like to send the reports to folders _bookCustomer1, _bookCustomer2, ... and then publish them as separate 'books' from RStudio.  Does anyone know how to do that?  Or could somebody recommend an alternative way to publish the finished books (reports) one for each customer?

Thank you,
Phil,